# irssi: What to do if I have more than 19 irssi windows?

Tags: command-line, keyboard-shortcuts, irssi

I hang out on several separate networks, and on several channels on each network, and in the end, this results in more than 19 windows within irssi.  (I use `irssi` within `tmux`, if it matters.)

However, there are only 19 shortcuts for windows:  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to <kbd>0</kbd>, plus the <kbd>q</kbd> to <kbd>o</kbd> continuation, with the rest of the windows only being accessible through the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> enumeration.

Is there an easy way to group some channels together for easier access (such that similar channels share half of the screen on each window, for example, but without this affecting more popular channels), or, perhaps easier, have <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> to <kbd>l</kbd> access windows 20 to 29?

Comment: Great question here, been wondering this myself.

Answer (score 2):

Aaron Toponce has an interesting blog post on this [Here](https://pthree.org/2007/07/18/irssi-windows-1-throuh-80/)

Essentially you can bind additional meta keys to the extra windows. at the cost of other irssi keybindings. using the entire keyboard if you wish

```
/bind meta-1 change_window 1
/bind meta-2 change_window 2
/bind meta-3 change_window 3
...
/bind meta-o change_window 19
/bind meta-p change_window 20
/bind meta-a change_window 21
/bind meta-s change_window 22
/bind meta-d change_window 23
/bind meta-f change_window 24
/bind meta-g change_window 25
... etc
```

He goes on to using the shift keys to go beyond window 40 too by using the shift keys as well so

```
/bind meta-! change_window 41
```

is <kbd>Escape</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>